# Django Rest Framework, how to get number of objects of foreignkey inside another foreignkey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have three models `Store`, `Product` and `Order`

```
class Store(models.Model):
    ......

class Product(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, ...)

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product ...)
    delivered = models.BooleanField()
```

I want to create a `@property` for the `Store` model that calculates the number of orders that has its products and also has `delivered=True`

how will i go about in doing that?

Comment: Do you want your serializer to serialize the `property` too? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: yes.. it is going to be added to serializer.data for the store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your store model define the `property` as usual

```py
class Store(models.Model):
    ......
    
    @property
    def order_count(self):
        return Order.objects.filter(product__store=self, delivered=True).count()

class Product(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store, ...)

class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product ...)
    delivered = models.BooleanField()
```

Then in your serializer you have two ways to include the `order_count` property in your serializer -

1. Define a `SerializerMethodField` in `StoreSerializer`

```py
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   order_count = serilizers.SerializerMethodField()

   def get_order_count(self, instance):
       return instance.order_count # the property in store object

   class Meta:
       model = Store
       fields = ['other', 'fields', 'in', 'store', 'model', 'order_count']
```

2. Declare `order_count` as a `ReadOnlyField` in your `StoreSerializer`

```py
class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_count = serilizers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = ['other', 'fields', 'in', 'store', 'model', 'order_count']
```